# Responsiveness of Qt GUI

Tags: qt, qtgui

I'm doing a lot of activity in the Qt GUI thread on application startup (creating/preallocating and hiding literally over a thousand widgets, mostly as a runtime/initialization tradeoff, it's an embedded system that needs to stay responsive during it's operation).

The goal of a responsive operation has been met - but now I have a challenge of making the initialization more responsive. Threading the initialization off to the worker thread is not an option - most of the CPU load comes from within calls to QtGui, and those need to take place in the main thread.

So, I wonder if there is an option to yield the control over to the app to handle all the other events? do the redraws, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More cleanly, without needing to sprinkle your code with `processEvents()` calls: implement your creating/preallocating as slot(s). Make it one slot with encapsulated state machine (knowing what to do next), or do more slots, or delegate to some classes with common interface, depends on your design and taste. Upon each finished call to the slot, post the call to yourself again as queued connection.

```
slots: void makeWidget();
signals: void widgetMade();
...
connect(this,SIGNAL(widgetMade()),this,SLOT(makeWidget()),Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

That way, your widget creation will be queued equally to other GUI activity. The explicit 5th parameter qualifier is necessary, default `Qt::AutoConnection` would be resolved to `Qt::DirectConnection` because you are in the same thread. As a bonus, you could actually do a non-blocking progress bar of your initialization, given that you know how many widgets are to be initialized.

Comment: That's a great hint - in my case, 90% of the load comes from one particular function, creating and hiding differently-looking buttons and sliders based off an XML definition. Actually, uic might be hacked together to do something similar, but I'm not that much of a uic wizard. So, in my case, one processEvents solved the problem, but your solution has some serious elegance to it, especially the bonus!

Comment: (Ab)using the event loop is fun regardless of the platform, but particularly Qt is fun squared in how easy it is :-)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that my GoogleFu had abandoned me for a while:

```
qApp->processEvents()
```

This processes all the outstanding GUI events - just calling it often enough solves the problem.

Comment: Note this could cause an issue if any further nested event loop is invoked during the processEvents() call. For example, if a user performs some action which activates a modal dialog, the call to qApp->processEvents() won't return until the modal dialog is dismissed.

Comment: That's a good comment! Although it wouldn't affect our case - we're just displaying an animated 'Standby' splash screen with some feedback on what it currently going on - how would you deal with such a case of a modal dialog being open? Is @Pavel Zdenek's solution any better for such a case?

Comment: Yup, Pavel's solution has no such problem, so it could be applied more generally.  Nothing wrong with qApp->processEvents() when you know it will be safe, though :)